# Why is the GRUB menu and boot splash smaller than my actual screen size?

Tags: grub2, resolution, plymouth, ati

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04,
and when Im in the GRUB Menu there are black edges both at top/bottom and left/right.
The same way it is in the Plymouth Splash, but additionally Plymouth seems to be stretched like from 4:3 to 16:9.

I use an external AMD GPU and the propritary drivers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At that early stage in the boot process, both GRUB as well as the boot splash (Plymouth) use the basic [VESA VBE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions) video drivers and not the full-featured proprietary video driver.
- Many modern video cards support only a limited number of VBE resolutions since they aren't really used with a graphical desktop any more, only for boot,etc.
- Hence, the lower resolution used by GRUB/Plymouth manifests as a "smaller" screen size on your monitor
- As long as your Ubuntu Desktop works fine, this "problem" isn't really worth bothering about, to be honest.
- If you strongly believe your video card *should* support a full-resolution VBE mode, you can try telling GRUB that by editing the `/etc/default/grub` file and then running `sudo update-grub`:

  ```
  # The resolution used on graphical terminal
  # note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
  # you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
  #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480   # <--- Change this to your monitor's maximum resolution
  ```